# Upload multiple files

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, file-upload

In my aspx file i have **one text box (txtsubject)** and **One upload control** for uploading file and **One button** for saving data in database table (**tblDraft**),

My table design is like below. When i upload just one file, i do not have any problem. For attaching multiple files i dont know what I have to do? I have to change design of my table (tblDraft)?

```
FileId (int)-identiy (yes)
FileName (varchar)
Subject (varchar)
ContentType (varchar)
Data (varbinary(max))
Extention (varchar)
```

Comment: you have any problem for uploading multiple files with same table design?

Comment: Do you try to attach multilple files?Then what is the problem that you face?

Comment: What value you are passing for File Id? you can have one new field named "UploadID",that should be same for mutiple uploaded files.Based on this ID,you can fetch back the uploaded details to display.

Comment: now when i try to attach more file , it will be replaced by old one, about "uploadid" field i do not know how i have to get it's value for each submitting.also i have problem in showing 2 or more uploaded files on the screen , it should be by gridview?